# How can change my port into 4900 by using npm?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

How can I change my port into 4900 by using npm, because I can't change my port by using ng s --port 4900.

Message showing:

PS G:\PROJECTS\PetroHSE> ng s --port 4900
ng : The term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- ng s --port 4900
- ~~

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ng:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    and if I use npm s --port 4900 showing

PS G:\PROJECTS\PetroHSE> npm s --port 4900
NAME                      | DESCRIPTION          | AUTHOR          | DATE       | VERSION  | KEYWORDS
sfs4900                   | Transliteration…     | =petuomin       | 2016-11-02 | 0.0.1    | SFS-4900 sfs4900 standard romanization russian finnish transliteration
@alifd/theme-4900         | Powered By…          | =mark-ck…       | 2019-01-15 | 0.1.1    |
PS G:\PROJECTS\PetroHSE> npm start
How can I change port by using npm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you do not have angualar cli installed globally.
Many people do, but you certainly do not have to (I definitely prefer not to)

You can use 2 ways to accomplish what you want:

1. use npx: `npx ng serve --port=4900` or `npx ng s --port=4900` (`s` NOT `-s`)
2. edit the file `package.json` In here you will find a part with scripts. You'll see that by default `start` script has `ng serve` in it. Edit this to `ng serve --port=4900`, save and exit. Then just run `npm start`. This option is more useful if you always want to start the server locally on this port.

Comment: Message showing  PS G:\PROJECTS\PetroHSE> npx ng -s --port=4800
Available Commands:
  add Adds support for an external library to your project....
For more detailed help run "ng [command name] --help" while using npx ng -s --port=4800, its not working

Comment: My bad, I was a bit too quick. I edited the answer.

Comment: Excellent, it works (npx ng s --port=4900)

Answer (score 0):

it appears that Angular CLI is not installed globally.

Try running `npm install -g @angular/cli`

this command will install Angular CLI globally.